# How do i get my back (function) button to work? JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do I get my back button to work normally? I want to have every nav item to appear after clicking the back button. The point is that I need to make a nav bar like this. But not great at javascript. so would love to get some help with this.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>js test</title>
</head>
<body>



   <div class="container">

        <div>
            <button id="btn1" class="btn" onclick="toggleBtn()">
                back
            </button>
        </div>

    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a id="navHome"  class="Nav-item" onclick="toggleHome()"  href="#"> Home </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="navBlog" class="Nav-item" onclick="toggleBlog()" href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="navEten" class="Nav-item" onclick="toggleEten()" href="#">Eten</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="navThuis" class="Nav-item" onclick="toggleThuis()" href="#">Thuis</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container1">
    <h1 class="link"> hoe kan ik de terug button netjes hebben? ik wil wanneer ik op terug klik dat alle linkjes terug komt. dus Home, Blog, Eten, Thuis. <br> Want op dit moment werkt het alleen goed als je twee keer op iets drukt. <br> Bijvoorbeeld twee keer op home of twee keer op blog </h1>
</div>




</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS

```
function toggleHome() {

  document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("btn");
 
  document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("btnOnClick");

  document.getElementById("navBlog").classList.toggle("btn");
  document.getElementById("navEten").classList.toggle("btn");
  document.getElementById("navThuis").classList.toggle("btn");

 
 }

 function toggleBlog() {

  document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("btn");
 
  document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("btnOnClick");

  document.getElementById("navHome").classList.toggle("btn");
  document.getElementById("navEten").classList.toggle("btn");
  document.getElementById("navThuis").classList.toggle("btn");
 
 }

 function toggleEten() {
  document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("btn");
 
  document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("btnOnClick");

  document.getElementById("navHome").classList.toggle("btn");
  document.getElementById("navBlog").classList.toggle("btn");
  document.getElementById("navThuis").classList.toggle("btn");
 
 }

 function toggleThuis() {
  document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("btn");
 
  document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("btnOnClick");

  document.getElementById("navHome").classList.toggle("btn");
  document.getElementById("navEten").classList.toggle("btn");
  document.getElementById("navBlog").classList.toggle("btn");
 
 }


 function toggleBtn() {

  document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("btn");
 
  document.getElementById("btn1").classList.toggle("btnOnClick");

  document.getElementById("navHome").classList.toggle("link");
  document.getElementById("navBlog").classList.toggle("link");
  document.getElementById("navEten").classList.toggle("link");
  document.getElementById("navThuis").classList.toggle("link");

 
 }
```

CSS

```
*{
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.container{
  border: 5px solid white;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.container1{
  
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a{
  color: white;
}

.link{
  color: white;
}

a:hover{
  color: aqua;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.btn{
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px transparent;
  position: fixed;

  display: none;
}


.btnOnClick{
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

nav{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. Text filler. For some reason I had to do this or I wasn't able to post this insert at all. I am sorry.

Comment: what are you trying to do i didnt understand the problem, make it a bit clear so i can help you

Comment: I was thinking the same.  Hi Antony, is it that you want the back button to be a dropdown with all the other items then shown in that dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took a look at your code, but it is a bit redundant and therefore hard to manage. So I changed it a bit and managed to achieve your goal. Look at the code snippet below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
*{
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.container{
  border: 5px solid white;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a{
  color: white;
}

.link{
  color: white;
}

a:hover{
  color: aqua;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.btnOnClick{
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

  <div id="button-wrapper"></div>

  <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a id="navHome"  class="Nav-item" name="Home" onclick="toggle(this.id, this.name)"  href="#"> Home </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="navBlog" class="Nav-item" name="Blog" onclick="toggle(this.id, this.name)" href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="navEten" class="Nav-item" name="Eten" onclick="toggle(this.id, this.name)" href="#">Eten</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="navThuis" class="Nav-item" name="Thuis" onclick="toggle(this.id, this.name)" href="#">Thuis</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

  <script>

    function toggle(id, name) {
      const navWrapper = document.getElementById("nav-wrapper");
      navWrapper.innerHTML = `<ul class="nav"><li><a id="${id}" class="Nav-item" name="${name}" onclick="reverseToggle(this.id, this.name)" href="#">${name}</a></li></ul>`;

      const buttonWrapper = document.getElementById("button-wrapper");
      buttonWrapper.innerHTML = `<button type="button" class="btnOnClick" onclick="reverseToggle()">Back</button>`
    }

    function reverseToggle() {
      const navWrapper = document.getElementById("nav-wrapper");

      navWrapper.innerHTML = `<ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a id="navHome"  class="Nav-item" name="Home" onclick="toggle(this.id, this.name)"  href="#"> Home </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="navBlog" class="Nav-item" name="Blog" onclick="toggle(this.id, this.name)" href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="navEten" class="Nav-item" name="Eten" onclick="toggle(this.id, this.name)" href="#">Eten</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="navThuis" class="Nav-item" name="Thuis" onclick="toggle(this.id, this.name)" href="#">Thuis</a>
        </li>
    </ul>`;

    const buttonWrapper = document.getElementById("button-wrapper");
      buttonWrapper.innerHTML = ""
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I added a new toggle function that takes in 2 parameters that are used to generate a new list item dynamically. Each will contain a onclick event listener with a new reverseToggle function, which brings back the original content. When the first "toggle" function is clicked the button will also appear, and the button has an event listener that is linked to the reverseToggle function too. I'm sure there still is a better way to achieve this, but this works and the code is already much cleaner.

Comment: hey Dharman. i was trying to work with your code. as you saw from my code i am not really that great. But i was wondering if it is possible to add aditional items to the nav menu. like this. *clicks on home* and then you only have home and back. but is there a way i could get something under home? so home school library and so on.

Comment: i trie4d it with this code: $('.navbar ul li a').click(function() {
    $(".aditional").hide()
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).show();

})

but that didnt work.

Comment: Maybe you could add some if statements that check the id of the element that has been clicked. If Home was clicked, you could add some new list items to the code. If the id was different, so for example, Blog was clicked, you should add some other list items. This page explains if else and else if statements: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

However, I do think your code will get long and redundant. I strongly advise you to learn more about how to create a web page with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. There are tons of video's available (https://coder-coder.com/learn-web-development/)